# Reduzir Amostra

Tags: r, redes-neurais

Quero treinar uma rede neural. A RNA deve ter inputs de mesmo tamanho na camada de entrada. Tenho dados de parcelas, porem cada uma com tamanhos diferentes de informações. Gostaria de saber se tem uma maneira de reduzir as informações das parcelas, para que coincidam com a quantidade de menor valor. Segue um exemplo abaixo com quatro parcelas simuladas.

```
a <- rnorm(n = 10,mean = 20,sd = 2)
b <- rnorm(n = 15,mean = 23,sd = 2.5)
c <- rbinom(n = 13,prob = 0.8, size = 20)
```

**Resultado para as parcelas a, b e c.**

> a
>    [1] 15.05996 21.09127 16.79843 21.89805 19.20879 18.50987 19.13300 19.31934 19.02064 21.08707
>
> b
>    [1] 18.04905 22.54312 26.81323 24.89401 26.89529 21.52093 27.50467 21.75318 21.08223 26.07979 22.29155
>   [12] 20.54107 24.84216 23.86484 23.06512
>
> c
>    [1] 11 14 18 17 17 18 18 19 18 17 17 17 17

A parcela "a" é a que tem menor quantidade de informações (n = 10). Há alguma maneira para que eu reduza o os dados (n) das parcelas "b" e "c" para que fiquem com a mesma quantidade da parcela "a" (10) sem que eu perca a representação dessa parcela?

Por exemplo, minha parcela "c" tem dois valores abaixo de 15 e onze acima. Minha amostra dessa parcela, reduzindo três valores deveria ser comparável com a amostra original.

Comment: Pode reduzir aleatoriamente com `sample(b, 10)` e `sample(c, 10)`, que é o melhor a fazer, mas não há garantias de o resultado ter, no caso de `c`, 2 valores abaixo de 15. Isso não significa que `c` e `c.reduzido` não sejam comparáveis.

Comment: Tem alguma função sample que me mostre o quanto aquela aleatoriedade representa os dados reais? Porque se eu estratificar a amostra, tenho valores maiores em um extrato do que em outro.

Comment: Isso já é outro problema. Mas se quer só reduzir a amostra, com os dados que tem o `sample` mantém estatísticas tais como a média e a variância. Não exatamente iguais, mas tais que testes de hipóteses não rejeitam as hipóteses nulas de igualdade de médias e de variâncias.